# How to push a UIViewController without using a navigational controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to imitate the behaviour that can be observed with `SFSafariViewController`. When presented, the push transition animation is used just like with a root `UINavigationalController`. When doing an edge pan swipe right, the pop transition follows.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://google.com")!
let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
present(safari, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, I need the same transition to work with any other `UIViewController`.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Place", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can always present and dismiss with custom transitions. Check out this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/146692/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-2), it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CATransition` you can able to change the animation direction while presenting the `ViewController`

```
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Still works 6 years later, nice!!

Answer (score 0):

@Fuxing, It is not possible to push a view controller without navigation controller.Ther are two option to push a view controller.

1. Add a navigation controller to your viewController in the storyboard.
2. Create an object of the navigation controller.

   ```
   let viewToPush = YourViewController()
   let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewToPush)    
   nav.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)
   ```

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd option. My current view controller does not have a navigational controller.

Comment: Just copy the code mentioned in my answer and replace YourViewController with your own view controller.